# Wordpress CI/CD with database?

Tags: wordpress, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, drone.io

So, I want to implement CI/CD with wordpress project, but database is the problem.
Are there any solutions for some kind of "synchronization" of the database, at least not complete? Or at least some solution? Nevertheless, on a prod client can change something, for example, some kind of text, and it seems to me that this is not very important.
But for example, if we add a new slider to the site, we would like to be able to move the sliders for the slider from dev to the site.

I think that drone.io will be used.

Comment: did you figure it out yet?